# How to stop terminal from re-opening old windows at launch?

Tags: terminal

I have a java app that automatically launches when the machine boots.  The trouble is that when Terminal is shut down, it does not actually close the window for that app, and so the next time the machine boots the old window is still there, and a new one is created when the app launches.  So I get an additional tab/window every single day, forever.

System Preferences is already set to close windows when quitting an app.  How can I get Terminal to stop doing this and actually close its tabs/windows when it is quit?

Comment: How does the Java application relate to Terminal?

Comment: It doesn't per se, just wanted to include the detail in case it could somehow be relevant.  Main point is that a terminal window is opened at startup and something is done.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now: You have a Java application which gets launched on login, opens an application window, and also opens a Terminal window? And if you reboot, you get the Java application, it's window and a second Terminal window?

Comment: The application has no window.  It just opens up a network listener (it's a local network streamer) and the terminal window sits there.

Answer (score 1):

One way which won't interfere with any other apps is to clear the contents of the Saved Application State and set the folder to immutable.

**Paste this into the Terminal**

```
terminalSAS="$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState"
[[ -d "$terminalSAS" ]] &&
rm -rf "$terminalSAS" &&
mkdir -p "$terminalSAS" &&
chflags -R uchg "$terminalSAS"
```

**And to revert:**

```
terminalSAS="$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState"
chflags -R nouchg "$terminalSAS"
```

### Breakdown

```
#this sets a variable for the folder of Terminal's Window data
terminalSAS="$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState"

#check that the folder exists
[[ -d "$terminalSAS" ]] &&

#deletes the folder to clear saved window data
rm -rf "$terminalSAS" &&

#re-create blank folder
mkdir -p "$terminalSAS" &&

#set the folder to immutable (like the lock checkbox in Finder -> Get Info)
chflags -R uchg "$terminalSAS"
```

Comment: Wow... I completely don't understand that.  Feels a bit heavy-handed...  =/

Comment: @JVC open up Terminal and paste the whole block in there and press Enter

Comment: No I understand how to use it.  I don't understand what it does, and I don't generally like executing code I completely don't understand the function/purpose of.

Comment: @JVC I'll write explanatory comments..

Comment: @JVC Alternatively, Open up Finder.  ⌘⇧G and type `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState` - delete the contents, right click -> Get Info -> tick the `locked` box

Comment: Ahhh ok, now I think I follow.  So this is locking the "hidden" folder where the application window state is stored, for just Terminal in specific.  Nice... I will give this a spin!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  On reboot, the old window was once again still present behind the newly created one.

Comment: Also to be clear, the saved state folder is in fact still empty, so the lock worked.  It just didn't change anything.

Comment: @JVC What's the value of this `defaults read com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows`

Comment: @JVC If it's not 0 or doesn't exist, try `defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool 0`

Comment: Looks to be invalid syntax, gave me a man page. (it did not exist so I tried to write it)